# output statictext while processing python

Tags: python, wxglade

I have written code to perform a function that could take a while to perform and I would like there to be output to a text box. at the moment all the intermediate output message all come at the end

```
def main():
  self.progress_txt.AppendText("Processing")
  #do something
  self.progress_txt.AppendText("Processing2")
  #do something else
  self.progress_txt.AppendText("Finished")
```

is there a way i could get the output messages outputed while the process is still running

Comment: You need to post more code. Going only by what you've posted, you may need to tell the GUI to update after you append text, or give the GUI time to execute.

Comment: Thanks to Oliver I was able to sort it by adding
      self.progress_txt.Update()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Oliver I was able to sort it

```
def main():
  self.progress_txt.AppendText("Processing")
  self.progress_txt.Update()
  #do something
  self.progress_txt.AppendText("Processing2")
  self.progress_txt.Update()
  #do something else
  self.progress_txt.AppendText("Finished")
  self.progress_txt.Update()
```